# Determine if android app is opened from GCM notification message

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

When I reboot the device or kill the app I don't have control over the Intent properties, so I can't add an ID.

How to know if the app starts from a gcm notification message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you send GCM notification from the server or from GCM firebase console you can set key value pair. that key you will get in Intent, so once you get key then you can easily identify app open from GCM notification.

you can get intent using getIntent()

Comment: Thanks. How to get the value from the intent?

Comment: String key = getIntent().getStringExtra("your key");

Comment: the key is that you have set from the server or from GCM console, if you are using GCM console then you just go to advance then you will see that set of boxes for key-value pair.

Comment: I have tried this but it doesn't work. Are you sure this is the correct code?

Comment: yes, but make sure, if you have splash screen then you need to check in splash otherwise it will not give data in intent in next screen of splash...

Comment: Good thinking. Thank you very much sir.